# Rename the only worksheet in multiple workbooks in a chosen directory

Tags: vba, excel

I am at my wits end and have come to you for your help.

What I am trying to accomplish is to rename a single worksheet (the only worksheet), in multiple workbooks, in a chosen directory to the workbook file name in Excel.

I have found code that will work within a single workbook, however I do not know how to get it to work on multiple workbooks in a directory chosen by the user or ran from a batch/vbs file in the same directory.

Here is the code I was using on a single workbook:

```
Sub RenameSheet()
Dim wbname
wbname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "")
    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = wbname
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I want to be able to do this for all files in a folder chosen by the user or files in the same directory as a batch file/vbs executable file if there is a way to execute this from running either a batch or vbs file?

If there are questions or I have missing something, please let me know and I will answer to the best of my ability.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open File Dialog (Pick which books to modify)
2. Change sheet name to wbName (your code here)
3. Close File (Save)
4. Repeat 2 - 3 for all selected books

This will need modification if there is more than 1 sheet on any of the workbooks selected. IF there is only one sheet, `ActiveSheet` will suffice.

```
    Sub RenameSheet()

    Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
    Dim ImportFiles As FileDialog
    Dim FileCount As Long 'Count of workbooks selected
    Dim wbName As String

    'Open File Picker
    Set ImportFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With ImportFiles
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Pick Files to Adjust"
        .ButtonName = ""
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
        .Show
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Cycle through books
    For FileCount = 1 To ImportFiles.SelectedItems.Count
        Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(ImportFiles.SelectedItems(FileCount))
            wbName = Replace(CurrentBook.Name, ".xlsx", "")
            CurrentBook.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Name = wbName
            CurrentBook.Close True
    Next FileCount

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: What is `FileIdx`?

Comment: @GMalc that has to be a typo, He's trying to get the Next FileCount.  I have a pending edit

Comment: Updated and should work as expected (just now tested)

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak a couple of lines but this works beautifully.  Thank you urdearboy.

```
    Sub RenameSheet()

Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim ImportFiles As FileDialog
Dim FileCount As Long 'Count of workbooks selected
Dim wbName As String

'Open File Picker
Set ImportFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With ImportFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Pick Files to Adjust"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Cycle through books
For FileCount = 1 To ImportFiles.SelectedItems.Count
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(ImportFiles.SelectedItems(FileCount))
        wbName = Replace(CurrentBook.Name, ".xlsx", "") ' had to rework this line to the original
        CurrentBook.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Name = wbName
        CurrentBook.Close True
Next FileCount ' had to change this to FileCount to remove the error "invalid next control variable"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I made an edit to mine. I had `DisplayAlerts` on twice. One needs to be `ScreenUpdating` which will make this run faster.

Comment: Thank you again urdearboy.  I have adjusted with your changes.